# Como replicar elementos de forma dinâmica?

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando criar uma série de elementos repetidos sem saber a quantia de repetições que serão necessárias. Eu tenho um input no qual o usuário informará um valor númerico acima ou igual a 1 que refletirá na quantia de repetições necessárias.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="numeroRepeticoes">
```

O único comando de repetição que conheço é o ng-repeat (meu conhecimento em Angular não é muito amplo) mas neste caso ele não é apto. Algo como isto não funcionaria:

```
<div ng-repeat="{{ numeroRepeticoes }}">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O angular só fornece o ng-repeat mesmo pra iterar sobre um array definido no `$scope`. Mas você pode usar isso pra fazer uma sacanagem e iterar sobre um array "simbólico". Basicamente crie no `$scope` uma propriedade que vai conter o número de iterações desejadas e então crie uma função que retorna um array desse tamanho. Então você itera nesse array.

Em código, você teria

```
// Número inicial de iterações
$scope.numIteracoes = 1;

// Construção do array 'fake'
$scope.iterador = function (num) {
    return new Array(num);
}
```

A partir daí você pode usar o `ng-repeat` com esse array passando o número de iterações como parâmetro. Ou seja, se você quer repetir uma div seria

```
<div ng-repeat="num in iterador(numIteracoes) track by $index">
    <!-- códigos da div aqui -->
</div>
```

Perceba que como `numIteracoes` é uma propriedade do `$scope` você pode atualizar ela dinamicamente, por exemplo com um `input` com `ng-model` apontando para ele.

Esse `track by $index` serve pra você identificar os items pela posição no array. Você pode ver mais sobre essa sintaxe [aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes).

Answer (score 1):

Isso é possível criando manualmente um vetor de itens a ser exibido pelo [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) e associando um evento [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) ao campo para então regerar o vetor e atualizar a lista.

Considere o seguinte template:

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="numeroRepeticoes" ng-change="update()"/><br/>
Itens:
<div ng-repeat="item in items">Item {{ item }} ({{ $index }})</div>
```

E o seguinte código:

```js
var loopApp = angular.module('loopApp', []);
loopApp.controller('LoopCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.update = function() {
        $scope.items = [];
        var total = parseInt($scope.numeroRepeticoes);
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            $scope.items.push(i + 1);
        }
    };
});
```

Então, cada vez que o usuário digitar no campo, a função `update()` será chamada, a qual irá alterar o vetor `items`, o que resultará na lista sendo gerada conforme o número de itens.

### [Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/EqFDz/)